# Global Settings & Commands - OO Design Patterns

Tags: wpf, oop, design-patterns, configuration, application-settings

I am currently building a WPF application and have some system wide settings. Where is the best place to store these settings? App.Config file, Database or some other sort of XML file? (need to read and write).

My other issue is the application has two states (i.e. Admin Mode, Client Mode) and depending on the state the application behaves differently i.e. (Shut Down, Restart, Lock, Unlock etc.) This seems like a good case to implement the State design pattern... but the issue I am facing is that the running application is itself the context class. I am a bit confused... should I be implementing the Singleton Pattern? How is this best implemented?

Comment: 1. The method of storing your settings depends on the amount of settings, how and when they are retrieved, and how and when they are saved I guess. You can decouple the actual save/load logic from the usage logic by having a settings manager object that can have a different strategy for its save/load implementation and then switch the implementation at will if you find that one doesn't suit you. I usually use an XML file.  2. Your application itself being a context isn't a problem. It can have a state object that calls the methods on the app according to its state logic. <ol>

Comment: 1) Cheers. 
2) This is how I thought about implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is often easiest to store application settings using the Settings page of the Project Designer in Visual Studio. These settings can either be stored per user or per application. Either way, they can be saved easily by calling:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

They can be accessed similarly:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FirstUserSetting = "abc";
```

You can find out full details by taking a look at the [Managing Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) page on MSDN.

Regarding your second question, I would recommend using the State Design Pattern. Unfortunately, I didn't understand your problem with that, so please let me know what your issue is and I will try to address it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it :)

I have used the state design pattern before in my "business layer" where I have all my domain objects. But the state that I am trying to implement here is for the actual application itself which is really a static class? I only ever need one instance of the object?

Comment: @user2909756 Are you referring to the fact that your state member would also have to be static? Is that your issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not getting your problem. If you don't want to use your `MainWindow.cs` class as the context of the pattern, then just use another class... if you *do* want to use it as the context, it can still extend the `abstract State` base class. Please add an edit/update section to your question that clearly explains your problem in this area.